# Expressing complicated regular expressions concisely

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there some way to write this simple regular expression more concisely? (here I am using separate lines to improve readability, even though I normally wouldn't use them)

```
(
(regex (matches|corresponds to) string)
|
(string (matches|corresponds to) regex)
)
```

"string" and "regex" are switched around here, and I want to express this concisely. I want to avoid writing (matches|corresponds to) more than once.

Comment: It depends on the flavor--if any.  Not with POSIX, maybe with PCRE, but I'm not sure.  It's hard to think of a meta language that saves you the work, and yet is restricted to regular languages.

Comment: I'm using Javascript's regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is creating it dynamically instead of using a literal:

```
function or(){return "("+Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,"|")+")";}
var bidi = ["matches", or("regex", "string"), "corresponds to"];
return new RegExp(or(bidi.join(" "), bidi.reverse().join(" ")));
```